After changing the VBE configuration in the SeaBIOS from using I/O ports to using MMIO, Windows cannot boot
QEMU's std VGA, when using the PCI interface, provides both I/O ports and MMIO to configure VBE. SeaBIOS uses I/O ports by default to configure VBE. I tried modifying the VGA BIOS code in SeaBIOS to use MMIO for configuring VBE. During the BIOS stage, the VGA BIOS could read and write VBE registers via MMIO, but after entering the Windows booting, writing to VBE MMIO address causes a hang. Does anyone know why this happens?
I add printf to SeaBIOS & Qemu：

During the BIOS stage, dispi (VBE) can read/write register through mmio. The qemu's pci_vga_bochs_write function handles these MMIO access requests.

During the Windows booting, the VGA BIOS issueds an MMIO write request, but the pci_vga_bochs_write function in QEMU was not called. As a result, the memory access could not be completed, causing the system to hang.
I would be very grateful if someone could answer my question.

Addressing the MMIO registers doesn't work in real mode, which why the vgabios uses the ioports.
Device initialization works because that uses big real mode (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreal_mode).
